# how to do the hyper parameter tunning for one class svm in r programming?

Tags: svm, hyperparameter, one-class, tuning

x is input (single column)

```
tuned <- tune.svm(x=x, y =NULL, data=x,
type= 'one-classification',
tunecontrol = tune.control(sampling = "fix"))
```

For this I am  getting error:

> Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula

Can anyone please help me to get rid of this error or the correct code for tuning of one class SVM?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a one-class svm, which is essentially an unsupervised training algorithm. In this case, there is no actual label for you to assess how good / bad your model is. You cannot measure the error, and if that's the case, running tune will not work.

If you are running one class svm for outlier detection, you need say a test set to define what are correct / wrong predictions, which then can give you a test error for you to choose the best parameters.

If you try to run something, it gives you purely rubbish, for example:

```
fit =  tune.svm(x=x,y=rep(TRUE,nrow(x)),type='one-classification', kernel="radial",nu=c(0.05,0.1,0.2))
fit$performances
    nu error dispersion
1 0.05   0.4  0.1763834
2 0.10   0.4  0.1763834
3 0.20   0.4  0.1763834
```

My suggestion is to go back and

1. define how you are going to assess how good the model is
2. come up with test and train set
3. run svm using the above to assess it

Comment: Thank you for reply, the example you have given is for one class svm ?, also i have fit the svm model for one class svm, there is no error in that but i am getting error while tuning that model, so able not able to understand that error.if i have done any mistake while tuning one class svm please let me that.

Comment: what is the exact code used? You gave y=NULL, in your question. That's not going to work. In the example I provided it's 3 classes, but that's not the issue. The issue is you are not giving the function the correct input

Comment: x i s my input. since it is one class svm , there is no y or we can say y is constant.

Comment: train the svm with hyper parameter tuning to get the best model with minimum error.

Comment: hey, i think we are going around in circles. How do you get minimum error with one class svm? How do define what is error when there is no labels